# How to re-define a protocol extension from a child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol with an extension that defines the functions:

```swift
protocol DataFetch where Self: UIViewController {
    var data: [SomeData]! { get set }
    func fetchData()
    func didFetch()
}

extension DataFetch {
    func fetchData() {
        /// fetch data
    }
    func didFetch() {
        /// do something after fetching data
    }
}
```

Then, I have a view controller that conforms to the protocol as well as a child view controller that inherits from the parent view controller:

```swift
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, DataFetch {
    var data: [SomeData]! {
        didSet {
            didFetch()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
    }
}

class ChildViewController: ParentViewController {
    func didFetch() {
        /// do something else
    }
}
```

I would like to override one of the inherited functions in the child view controller, but since you cannot do that with a protocol extension, I tried to simply re-define the function definition. But, I find that the re-defined function in the child view controller doesn't get called within `didSet`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry that was a typo. I'm already inheriting from the parent view controller, but the method is still not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a workaround but since didSet seems to only handle the current scope (ParentViewController) and not sees what is defined in the ChildViewController and also since you can not use the `override` keyword when implementing `didFetch` in the ChildViewController to force it to be used this solution introduces a new function so we can make `override` to work as expected

First create a new function in the parent controller and call it from `didSet` as below

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, DataFetch {
    var data: [String]! {
        didSet {
            workaround()
        }
    }

    func workaround() {
        didFetch()
    }
    //...
}
```

and now override this function in the child controller and the correct `didFetch` will be called

```
class ChildViewController: ParentViewController {
    override func workaround() {
        didFetch()
    }
    //...
}
```